# Why is TH `newtype Q` documented as `data Q` on Hackage?

Tags: haskell

Is [this](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/template-haskell-2.13.0.0/docs/src/Language.Haskell.TH.Syntax.html#Q) a documentation bug or something else?

Comment: It looks like Haddock always typesets abstract datatypes (that is, datatypes exported without their constructors) using `data`. Whether this is a bug or a feature I cannot say.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not a bug. Haddock prints all abstract types as `data`. The thought is this: the type is being held abstract so that the library author can change the internal representation without the users knowing (or needing to). Since the library author might change between `newtype` and `data`, and the users are not supposed to know about this, both ways of creating a new type must be presented the same way in the haddocks.

Given that, the choice between using `newtype` for both or `data` for both seems clear to me: `data` is much more frequently used and more easily understood for beginners.